# Multidimensional Array to Multidimensional SimpleXMLElement (XML Object)

Tags: php, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array

Im having some trouble with creating an Multidimensional SimpleXMLElement, it works well with simple Array's but when there are multidimensional Array the SimpleXMLElement wont write in multid SimpleXMLEelement. Like this:

**createXML function:**

```
public function createXML($data, $root = null) {
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($root ? '<' . $root . '/>' : '<marathon/>');
    array_walk_recursive($data, function($value, $key)use($xml){
        $xml->addChild($key, $value);
    });

    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
    $dom->encoding = "UTF-8";
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    print $dom->saveXML();
}
```

**This prints:**

```
<marathon>
  <media_id>FACE</media_id>
  <agreement_id>****</agreement_id>
  <client_reference>123456</client_reference>
  <client_contact>Asim</client_contact>
  <plan_number>407</plan_number>
  <plan_name>TEST</plan_name>
  <cuid>123456</cuid>
  <status>P</status>
  <colour>0</colour>
  <insertion_date>2018-09-19</insertion_date>
  <end_date>2018-09-20</end_date>
  <client_reference>1234</client_reference>
  <price_code>0</price_code>
  <number_of_units>250000</number_of_units>
  <gross>1000</gross>
  <comment>THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER</comment>
</marathon>
```

**When what i want is:**

```
<marathon>
  <media_id>FACE</media_id>
  <agreement_id>REDP</agreement_id>
  <client_reference>123456</client_reference>
  <client_contact>Asim Tariq</client_contact>
  <plan_number>407</plan_number>
  <plan_name>TEST</plan_name>
  <cuid>123456</cuid>
  <status>P</status>
  <colour>0</colour>
     <insertion>
        <insertion_date>2018-09-19</insertion_date>
        <end_date>2018-09-20</end_date>
        <client_reference>1234</client_reference>
              <price_row>
                  <price_code>0</price_code>
                  <number_of_units>250000</number_of_units>
                  <gross>1000</gross>
                  <comment>THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER</comment>
             </price_row>
     </insertion>
</marathon>
```

How can i manage this with the code i have in `createXML` ? The XML does not get multidimensional?

**This is the Array i send in as** `$data:`

```
[
            "media_id" => 'FACE',
            "agreement_id" => 'REDP',
            "client_reference" => 123456,
            "client_contact" => "Asim Tariq",
            "plan_number" => 407,
            "plan_name" => "TEST",
            "cuid" => 123456,
            "status" => 'P',
            "colour" => 0,
            "insertion" => [
                "insertion_date" => '2018-09-19',
                "end_date" => '2018-09-20',
                "client_reference" => 1234,
                "price_row" => [
                    "price_code" => 000,
                    "number_of_units" => 250000,
                    "gross" => 1000,
                    "discount" => [

                    ], 
                 "comment" => "THIS IS A TEST DO NOT FAKTURER",
                ],
            ],
        ]
```

Comment: Well right now you are only ever appending elements to the root element, `$xml->addChild()` - so that part would have to be changed accordingly, in a way that you somehow pass in the correct current parent element to work with.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer its not a duplicate. I am having trouble not only adding elements to root. The link you provide does not give this details.

Comment: Yes @misorude it looks like even the "insertion" key is missing and the key/value inside that array is put on root element. How can i make it a key and add elements inside that in XML?

Comment: Have your tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965940/8913537) answer?

Comment: Yes @PhilippMaurer. Im getting errors like this on that function: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object

Comment: _“it looks like even the "insertion" key is missing”_ - probably due to the fact that you are trying to do `addChild($key, $value)` in that case as well, even though the value in this case will itself be an array. You would need to differentiate between those two cases. Not sure if `array_walk_recursive` is the best way to go about this; a self-written function that calls itself recursively might be the better alternative.

Comment: @Asim You probably did not provide a `SimpleXMLElement` as `$xml_data` then. Give that answer another chance. It is most likely the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for `array_walk_recursive`, "any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function".

Write a recursive function instead which adds the value to a subelement if it is an array. For example:

```
private function addXMLData(\SimpleXMLElement $xml, array $data)
{
    array_walk($data, function($value, $key) use($xml){
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $child = $xml->addChild($key);
            self::addXMLData($child, $value);
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    });
}

public function createXML($data, $root = null) {
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($root ? '<' . $root . '/>' : '<marathon/>');

    self::addXMLData($xml, $data);

    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml)->ownerDocument;
    $dom->encoding = "UTF-8";
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    print $dom->saveXML();
}
```

Comment: Yes so array_walk_recursive is then not possible to use. I tried just fast copy/paste your code to check if it works out of box, but i get this error: Using $this when not in object context. This is well related to private/public function?. The method i use to call the function createXML: $request_xml = self::createXML($request);

Comment: I've edited the answer correspondingly. I didn't realise you were calling the function statically.

Comment: Thats my fault sorry @Matt. Your solution work perfectly now!! Thanks alot :)